# How to get ZombieJS+NodeJS to run over a collection?

Tags: node.js, headless-browser, zombie.js

My naive approach to get ZombieJS to loop over an huge array of items was to add the following code inside my for loop

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://localhost:3000/", function () {

  // Fill email, password and submit form
  browser.
    fill("email", "zombie@underworld.dead").
    fill("password", "eat-the-living").
    pressButton("Sign Me Up!", function() {

      // Form submitted, new page loaded.
      assert.ok(browser.success);
      assert.equal(browser.text("title"), "Welcome To Brains Depot");

    })

});
```

but all sort of errors ensued. Specially memory errors after trying to load the 100th item.

What am I doing wrong? I wish I could run this every iteration of the loop and also cleaning the resource after every successful try.

Comment: You're effectively trying to tell the browser to visit all your items at the same time.  Don't call the next `.visit()` until your callback after `pressButton`.

Comment: how can I do that inside a for loop?

Comment: I just posted an answer.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would create a queue of URLs to visit...

```
var urls = ['http://example.com/something', 'http://example.com/somethingElse', /* etc. */]
```

Then, I would create a function that reads from this queue.

```
function runNextJob() {
    if (!urls.length) {
      return; // W're done!
    }

    var url = urls.pop();
    browser.visit(url, function () {
        // yada yada
        browser.pressButton('Sign Me Up!', function () {
            // On next tick, call runJext Job().  It's important that
            // this is next tick!  Otherwise our call stack gets enormous.
            process.nextTick(runNextJob);
        }
    }
}
```

To start the cycle, just call `runNextJob()` once.  If you want to run multiple at a time, run that function as many times as you want to have simultaneous jobs.  (Say, 4 times for a 4 CPU box, depending on how `browser` does its work, but you'll want to experiment.)